# How do I pass two arguments to a scope method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, activerecord

I am trying to display a list based on a date being selected via a link_to. I want to be able to select a link in the view and only display a list from a previous day or a future day. The default is the current date. Here is what I have so far.

**Model**

```
def self.date_filter(begin_date, end_date)
    where("date BETWEEN ? AND ?", begin_date, end_date )
end
```

**Controller**
   This works as the default which should be the current date.

```
@list = Location.date_filter(Date.today.beginning_of_day, Date.today.end_of_day)
```

**View**

```
<%= link_to -1.days.from_now.strftime('%a %d'), locations_path %><br />
<%= link_to Date.today.strftime('%a %d'), locations_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass the date you want to filter into your controller

```
<%= link_to((@date -1.day).strftime('%a %d'), locations_path(:date => @date -1.day)) %><br />
<%= link_to(@date.strftime('%a %d'), locations_path(:date => @date)) %>


@list = Location.date_filter(@date, @date.end_of_day)
```